# CMake: cannot get add_custom_command to fit the appropriate make pattern

Tags: cmd, makefile, cmake, gnu-make

I am using CMake to generate a Unix Makefile to build a C project for microcontrollers.
To collect the compiler warnings, I modified the compile command

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE> 2> <OBJECT>.err")
```

This redirects the compiler warnings of say foo.c.o,  to foo.c.o.err

Now I would like to merge all the .err files into a single one. Since the linker has access to all the object files, I though of adding a custom command to the target after the build.

```
add_custom_command( TARGET Debug POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND type $(addsuffix .err,$(subst /,\,$(Debug_OBJECTS))) > $@.err)
```

I use the objects list, add .err to each one. I replace the / with \ inside the paths.
If I manually insert the command in the makefile, it works.
But CMake generates the command like this:

```
type $ ( addsuffix .err,$ ( subst /,,$(Debug_OBJECTS) ) ) > $@.err
```

Due to the added spaces and the missing ,  the command does not work anymore.

Any idea how I can avoid this ?
Or maybe suggest a better way how to merge all the .err files into one ?

Comment: Hard to test with such a little piece of code, but did you try adding `VERBATIM` keyword and/or quote around your function?

Comment: VERBATIM actually made it worse :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after 4 hours of trial and error.

Each space character is considered a delimiter for a new argument of the function add_custom_command. e.g. TARGET, POST_BUILD, COMMAND etc..
CMake interprets parenthesis which leads to the padding. All I needed is to tell CMake, this is a string, hands off and pass it as is!

But the arguments of the add_custom_command are generator expressions see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)

So i split my desired command where the space characters are and give each sequence as a dummy generator expression. I also make sure to escape special characters like $ and parentheses. It was very tricky with the redirection >
I used the expression $<1:string>

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Debug POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND $<1:type> $<1:$\(addsuffix> $<1:.err,$\(subst>
                           $<1:/,\\,$\(Debug_OBJECTS\)\)\)> > $@.err )
```

It's ugly, but it worked. I am pretty sure there is a far better way. At the end of the day, all I'm trying to do is to create a command very similar to the link executable command. I know hot to modify the latter, but I don't know to to create a similar one using the same syntax :-(

If anyone has clue, please share